# how can I call a specific function in wordpress from a plugin admin page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins

I created my wordpress admin page, but I need to submit a form and save the results, I checked the info on internet and many do it on same php page, but I want to use a different, for this, I firstly want to create a function in myplugin.php and submit my form to that edit , is it possible to do that??

```
http://myurl/wp-admin/admin.php?page=Info
```

So, now I am from this page, my main plugin file is plugin.php, I want to create a function inside called something and call it from my submit form , how can I do that? or , is there any other way to submit form in this way??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This hook allows you to create custom handlers for your own custom GET and POST requests. The admin_post_ hook follows the format "admin_post_$youraction", where $youraction is your GET or POST request's 'action' parameter.

If you needed to create an request or form handler for an "add_foobar" action request, you would create a hook like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' );

function prefix_admin_add_foobar() {
    // Handle request then generate response using echo or leaving PHP and using HTML
}
```

Using the above example, any time a GET or POST request is sent to WordPress, and the request's 'action' parameter is set to 'add_foobar', this hook will be automatically executed. For example, the following HTML content would execute the above hook when the user clicks either Submit.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=add_foobar&data=foobarid">Submit</a>
<form action="http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_foobar">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="foobarid">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Note: The data value (foobarid) would be available in your hook function from the `$_GET, $_POST` or `$_REQUEST` array as is applicable.

Well,

Apparently, I need to use an action, the reference is in here

[http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_%28action%29)

Comment: how to actually generate the response? if you just echo the content, it will show the content without the actual dashboard.